# Why is my PHP child class not getting public and protected vars from the parent?

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I'm having brainfreeze, and I suspect this one is really simple.
Consider this code, with two classes:

```
<?php    
class myparentclass {
    protected $vara;
    private $varb;
    public $varc;
    public $_childclass;

    function __construct() {
        $this->vara = "foo";
        $this->varb = "bar";
        $this->varc = ":(";
        $this->_childclass = new mychildclass;    
    }
}

class mychildclass extends myparentclass {
    function __construct() {
        print_r ($this);
    }
}

print "<pre>";
$foo = new myparentclass();
```

The output is:

```
mychildclass Object
(
    [vara:protected] => 
    [varb:private] => 
    [varc] => 
    [_childclass] => 
)
```

I know $varb shouldn't be set, but what about the others?

Comment: Told you it was simple! +1 all, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a new `__construct()` in the child class as you've done to print vars out, you need to explicitly call the parent's constructor too.  If you did not define any `__construct()` in the child class, it would directly inherit the parent's and all those properties would have been set.

```
class mychildclass extends myparentclass {
  function __construct() {
    // The parent constructor
    parent::__construct();
    print_r ($this);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the parent class constructor inside the child class constructor.

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        print_r ($this);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you re-define the constructor in your child class, you have to call the parent constructor.

```
class mychildclass extends myparentclass {
 function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();
     print_r ($this);
 }
}
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If the child class has it's own constructor, you must explicitly call the parent constructor from within it (if you want it called):

```
parent::__construct();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parent constructor is never executed by the child. Modify mychildclass like this:

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    print_r ($this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overriding the parent class' constructor with the constructor in your parent class. You can call the parent's constructor from your child class with parent::__construct();

However the last line of the constructor of myparentclass calls the constructor of mychildclass which in turn calls the parent constructor, et cetera. Did you mean to achieve this?

```
<?php    
class myparentclass {
    protected $vara;
    private $varb;
    public $varc;

    function __construct() {
        $this->vara = "foo";
        $this->varb = "bar";
        $this->varc = ":(";
    }
}

class mychildclass extends myparentclass {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        print_r ($this);
    }
}

print "<pre>";
$foo = new mychildclass();
```